# Is there a way to safely reload jetty?

Tags: jetty

is there a way to reload jetty ? For example if I have separate java apps running on same jetty instance and I want one of those apps restarted, but don't want any other apps to be affected by that restart, how can I achieve that ?

Or the only way to achieve that is running one jetty per app ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are deploying with a webapp (`*.war`) file or context xml file `*.xml` in the `${jetty.base}/webapps/` directory, just touch the file (update its timestamp) and that specific webapp will reload automatically.

You could also copy a fresh copy of the webapp or context xml file over top of the existing one (this will also trigger a reload)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you asked this on the Jetty-Users mailing list as well. Reposting [the answer that Simone Bordet provided](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg07393.html), which is to use JMX to restart the affected context/webapp:

> You can enable JMX and then stop() and start() again the context of
>   the application you want to restart.
>   http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/jmx-chapter.html.
>
> The webapp contexts are typically under ObjectNames of the form:
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp:type=webappcontext,*